# Post Notification is not called from application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: objective-c, ios8, push, xcode6, nsnotificationcenter

I am getting push notification from server but my postNotification is not being called. It is correctly entering in if statement which states that type == 1. All the user defaults are correctly stored but the notification is not being called. I put the break point as well as an alert in the function of view controller which is called by the post notification. But it never being called.  Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 if(launchOptions != nil)
   {
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (dictionary != nil)
    {
        NSString *type = [dictionary objectForKey:@"type"];
        if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",type]integerValue]==1)
        {

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"] forKey:@"message"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"senderid"] forKey:@"senderID"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"sendername"] forKey:@"sendername"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"userimage"] forKey:@"pushImage"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

            NSLog(@"message is %@",[[dictionary objectForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"]);
            NSLog(@"senderID is %@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"senderid"]);
            NSLog(@"sender name is %@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"sendername"]);

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:launchOptions];

        }

   }

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
#endif

UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |     UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];


application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=FALSE;
return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer of my own question. Here is the code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[FBLoginView class];
self.mainNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;


if(launchOptions != nil)
{
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if (dictionary != nil)
    {
        NSString *type = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[dictionary valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"json"] valueForKey:@"type"]];
        NSLog(@"type is %@",type);

        if ([type isEqualToString:@"0"]) // 0 means NOW
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[[[dictionary valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"json"] valueForKey:@"yadda_sub_type"] forKey:kYaddaSubType_Push];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[[[dictionary valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"json"] valueForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:kYaddaUserID_Push];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[[[dictionary valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"json"] valueForKey:@"yadda_id"] forKey:kYaddaID_Push];

            ReciversSideVC *reciverControoler = [[ReciversSideVC alloc]init];
            [reciverControoler.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
            [reciverControoler.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
            [AppDelegateClass.mainNavigationController pushViewController:reciverControoler animated:NO];
        }

        else if ([type isEqualToString:@"1"]) // 1 means LATER
        {
            if (isCalendarScreenOpen==YES)
            {
                CalendarVC *calendar = [[CalendarVC alloc]init];
                [calendar.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
                [calendar.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
                [AppDelegateClass.mainNavigationController pushViewController:calendar animated:NO];
            }
        }

        else if ([type isEqualToString:@"2"]) // 2 means Remind me
        {
            LandingPageVC *landing = [[LandingPageVC alloc]init];
            [landing.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
            [landing.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
            [AppDelegateClass.mainNavigationController pushViewController:landing animated:NO];
        }

        else if ([type isEqualToString:@"3"]) // 3 means Reply
        {
            LandingPageVC *landing = [[LandingPageVC alloc]init];
            [landing.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
            [landing.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
            [AppDelegateClass.mainNavigationController pushViewController:landing animated:NO];
        }

        else if ([type isEqualToString:@"4"]) // 4 means Contacts
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"flag_CallAPI"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
            ContactDetailVC *contactDetails = [[ContactDetailVC alloc]init];
            contactDetails.userID = [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"json"] valueForKey:@"user_id"];
            contactDetails.phoneNumberFromServer = [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"json"] valueForKey:@"phone_number"];
            [contactDetails.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
            [contactDetails.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
            [AppDelegateClass.mainNavigationController pushViewController:contactDetails animated:NO];
        }

    }
}


UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif != nil)
{
    NSDictionary *NotificationValue = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"localPushNotification"];

    if (NotificationValue != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Run with notification value: %@", NotificationValue);

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NotificationValue valueForKey:@"yadda_sub_type"] forKey:kYaddaSubType_Push];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NotificationValue valueForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:kYaddaUserID_Push];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NotificationValue valueForKey:@"yadda_id"] forKey:kYaddaID_Push];

        ReciversSideVC *reciverControoler = [[ReciversSideVC alloc]init];
        [AppDelegateClass.mainNavigationController pushViewController:reciverControoler animated:NO];

    }
}


if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}

UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |     UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=FALSE;

return YES;
}
```